# Strange gray rectangle (like selection) on upper left in contenteditable div in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used Vue to implement a contenteditable div.
But there was a gray area on upper left when I hovered the div.
The situation occurred in Chrome only. It worked perfect in Safari, Firefox.

And the gray area wasn't a DOM. It was something like selection.

[image: e]

This is my code:

```
<div
   ref="exer-input-textarea"
   :class="{'textarea': true, 'fixed-size': box === false}"
   contenteditable="true"
   v-html="modelValue"/>
```

CSS

```
.exer-input, .exer-textarea-box-input
   & .textarea
     width: 100%
     font-size: 16px
     outline: none
     color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)
     line-height: 2.1
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
     word-wrap: break-word

   & .fixed-size
     overflow: scroll
     max-height: 100px
```

Comment: Hi! Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Use the chrome devtools to see what is causing this gray area.
Right click on the div and choose inspect. Then in the devtools check for the gray area in the css and html generated.
You can play around with :active, :focus etc by clicking on ":hov" on the styles tab.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: Nothing detected or changed.

Comment: Do you have a link to the live code or is it only local?

Comment: It is only local. It's a private project :(